# Sorting in XSL apply-templates nodes using other nodes from a variable (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath

**How to sort `<foo name="..."/>` nodes from $foo using their corresponding node order from $bar?**

<s>Partial solution (Mark Veenstra)</s>

```
<xsl:for-each select="$list-resources">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$building-resources[@name = current()/@name]">
        <xsl:with-param name="param" select="$some-value"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

New problem (see edit at the end of the question):

**How to retrieve the position in the whole sorted node set of each $building-resources node?**

---

### **TL;DR answer**

- The `<xsl:sort/>` has an attribute, `@data-type`, to specify the type of data in the `@select` node. *Default is "text". Since I compare numbers, I must set* `@data-type="number"`. Else, the text comparison fails when it comes to compare 9 and 10.
- `<xsl:sort select="count($bar[@name = current()/@name]/preceding-sibling::*)" data-type="number"/>`
- In `<xsl:sort/>`, `current()` refers to the currently sorted node (not to the `<xsl:template/>` current node)

Thanks to michael.hor257k

---

### **Complete Answer**

**Code**

```
    <!-- Resource "instances" to order, using $list-resources -->
    <xsl:variable name="building-resources"
        select="document('building.xml')/building/resource"/>

    <result>
        <!-- Apply templates to the resource instances -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$building-resources">
            <!-- Sort using the nodes order from the resources list -->
            <!-- Don't forget the @data-type: we're comparing NUMBERS not TEXTS -->
            <xsl:sort
                select="count($list-resources[@name = current()/@name]/preceding-sibling::*)"
                data-type="number"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Template to apply for each resource of $building-resources -->
<xsl:template match="ressource">
    <!-- position() refers to the node position in $building-resources
    because we used $building-resources as @select value
    of the apply-templates -->
    <output position="{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

*Inputs*

list-resources.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource name="wood"/>
    <resource name="stone"/>
    <resource name="gold"/>
</resources>
```

building-resources.xml

```
<building>
    <resource name="stone"/>
    <resource name="gold"/>
    <resource name="stone"/>
    <resource name="wood"/>
    <resource name="wood"/>
</building>
```

*Output*

```
<result>
    <output position="1">wood</output>
    <output position="2">wood</output>
    <output position="3">stone</output>
    <output position="4">stone</output>
    <output position="5">gold</output>
</result>
```

---

### **Original question**

**Sorting**

I have two XML documents:

A list of resources (`list-resources.xml`, like a "class" list):

```
<resources>
    <resource name="wood"/>
    <resource name="stone"/>
    <resource name="gold"/>
</resources>
```

And resources inside a building (`buildings.xml`, like "objects" list):

```
<building>
    <resource name="stone"/>
    <resource name="gold"/>
    <resource name="stone"/>
    <resource name="wood"/>
    <resource name="wood"/>
</building>
```

I want to order the `<resource/>` nodes from `<building/>` so it matches the `<resource/>` order from `<resources/>`. This is the desired output:

```
<result>
    <output position="1">wood</output>
    <output position="2">wood</output>
    <output position="3">stone</output>
    <output position="4">stone</output>
    <output position="5">gold</output>
</result>
```

To do so, I have two node-sets in a XSL:

```
<xsl:variable name="building-resources" select="building/resource"/>
<xsl:variable name="list-resources" select="resources/resource"/>
```

And I use an XSL apply-templates to treat nodes from `$building-resources`:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$building-resources">
    <xsl:with-param name="some-param" select="$variable-from-somewhere"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Let's say the applied templates is ok. My currently not-sorted result is:

```
<result>
    <output position="1">stone</output>
    <output position="2">gold</output>
    <output position="3">stone</output>
    <output position="4">wood</output>
    <output position="5">wood</output>
</result>
```

Now, I added a `<xsl:sort/>` element to sort my nodes from `$building-resources`, but I don't know what to put inside its `@select`...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$building-resources">
    <xsl:sort select="what-to-put-here"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="some-param" select="$variable-from-somewhere"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I tried the following XPath expression:

```
count($list-ressources[@name = current()/@name]/preceding-sibling::*)
```

<s>But inside this XPath, `current()` refers to the node treated by the `<xsl:template/>` where `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is.
So, instead of `current()`,</s> 
But this doesn't work, the result is not correctly sorted.
I would mean *"the node the `<xsl:sort/>` process is currently treating"* *(edit: this is actually exactly what current() does!)* inside my XPath brackets `$list-resources[]`. How do I do so?

---

**Get the sorted position**

Since I simplified the code, I forgot something... Mark Veenstra's solution raised up a problem.

In the applied template (the template that generates the `<output/>` node), I use `position()` to get the position of the node the template is applied on:

```
<xsl:template match="resource">
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
    <output position="{$position}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

This works well as long as I do only "one" apply-templates (hence the `position()` inside the this applied template holds the position of the node in the sorted list). But if I apply Mark's solution (note that `current()` inside the `<xsl:sort/>` now refers to the node from the `<xsl:for-each/>` aka from $liste-resources):

```
<xsl:for-each select="$list-resources">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$building-resources[@name = current()/@name]">
        <xsl:with-param name="param" select="$some-value"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then the `position()` inside the applied template refers to the position of the node in the *partial* node set ($building-resources[@name = current()/@name]).

How to fix that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287651/xslt-custom-sort

Comment: @MarkVeenstra I don't want to sort `$building-resources` using one of their own attribute (`@name` in that other question), but using another node set. So I don't get how these questions could be related.

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the sorting problem, I would suggest:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <building>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="building/resource">
            <xsl:sort select="count(document('list-resources.xml')/resources/resource[@name = current()/@name]/preceding-sibling::resource)" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </building>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="resource">
    <resource position="{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </resource>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, this returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<building>
   <resource position="1">wood</resource>
   <resource position="2">wood</resource>
   <resource position="3">stone</resource>
   <resource position="4">stone</resource>
   <resource position="5">gold</resource>
</building>
```

I am not sure what the other problem is.

Comment: Oh, gosh.... I've forgotten the `@data-type`... It defaults to "text", so all my sort was done in text and failed when count()=9 vs 10... Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try to do something like the following. (untested)

Change:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$building-resources">
    <xsl:sort select="what-to-put-here"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="some-param" select="$variable-from-somewhere"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

To:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$list-resources/@name">
    <xsl:variable name="curName" select="." />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$building-resources[@name = $curName]">
        <xsl:with-param name="some-param" select="$variable-from-somewhere"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So before applying the templates, make sure you apply in the order of the other nodeset. That's why I added an extra `for-each` around it.

Comment: Works nice, and `$building-resources[@name = current()/@name]` is even shorter. But I now have another problem (see edit "Get the sorted position") since there are "several node sets" the template is applied to, so it "breaks" the `position()` function inside the applied template.

Comment: `current()` is causing problems I guess. It is something different than my solution given. Have you tried using my solution?

Comment: Same problem. I suspect `position()` to be bounded to the `<xsl:apply-templates/>`'s node set, aka to refer to the position of the node inside `$building-resources[@name = $curName]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an XSL key and `<xsl:sort>`, like this:

```
<xsl:key name="kResource" match="resources/resource" use="@name" />

<!-- regular identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- specialized identity template, adds a position attribute -->
<xsl:template match="*" mode="with-position">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="position"><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="building">
  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="with-position">
      <xsl:sort select="count(key('kResource', @name)/preceding-sibling::*)" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </result>
</xsl:template>
```

Relevant output:

```
<result>
  <resource position="1" name="wood" />
  <resource position="2" name="wood" />
  <resource position="3" name="stone" />
  <resource position="4" name="stone" />
  <resource position="5" name="gold" />
</result>
```

Note that even though I've added a `position` attribute, I think that's a rather unnecessary thing to have. XML elements have a natural position in the document, no need to be over-specific.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0, you cannot use key across documents.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Would switching the context node to the other document not be enough? In any case, the same approach applies without a key. `<xsl:sort select="count($other-doc-resources[@name = current()/@name]/preceding-sibling::*)" data-type="number" />`

Comment: "*Would switching the context node to the other document not be enough?*" It doesn't matter - the problem is connecting across the barrier (which is what key is all about). -- Your other suggestion is essentially the same as mine - except I removed the variables, since Xalan cannot handle them.

Comment: Just to clarify: switching context *would* work if you wanted to fetch the related value for the current node only; you'd just "go there" for a moment and come right back. But this cannot be done within `xsl:sort` when you are dealing with an entire node-set wholesale.

Comment: Yes, I've figured that much. :)