# XSLT switching order of elements

Tags: xml, xslt, sitecore

I need to switch elements e.g. as in this xml:

```
<configuration>
  <sites>
   <site name="site1"/>
   <site name="site2" />
   <site name="site3"/>
   <site name="site4"/>
  </sites>
</configuration>
```

to:

```
<configuration>
  <sites>
   <site name="site3"/>
   <site name="site4" />
   <site name="site1"/>
   <site name="site2"/>
  </sites>
</configuration>
```

through XSLT. Can anybody help with this transformation ?

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="site1" select="configuration/sites/site[@name='site1']" />

<xsl:variable name="site2" select="configuration/sites/site[@name='site2']" />

<xsl:template match="site[@name='site1'"/>
<xsl:template match="site[@name='site2'"/>


<xsl:template match="configuration/sitecore/sites">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$site1"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$site2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

What I tried to do is and I am not sure if I can use some variable to store all specific element content to it remove appropriate element copy rest of node and append it at the end.

Thanks

Krp0

Comment: What is the rule? Look up `xsl:sort` ...

Comment: I need that site1/site2 will be after definition of site3/site4. Have to be last in the output xml. And I have a lot of this site definitions and I identify them by their name.

Comment: please, update your question with an XSLT attempt. Here is a reference to starts with (if you haven't) : [XSLT Custom Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287651/xslt-custom-sort)

Answer (score 3):

If the desired order of `site` elements cannot be specified via the sort of pairwise ordering relationship needed by `xsl:sort`, perhaps you're looking to rearrange a predetermined set of `sites` based purely on a predetermined ordering distinguished only by their `@name` attributes:

### XSLT 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sites">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[@name='site3']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[@name='site4']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[@name='site1']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[@name='site2']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've shown this with the identity transformation for maximal flexibility, but you can ratchet back generality via `xsl:copy-of` rather than `xsl:apply-templates` etc.

---

### XSLT 2.0

In XSLT 2.0, a single `xsl:apply-templates` could be used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sites">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[@name='site3'],
                                   site[@name='site4'],
                                   site[@name='site1'],
                                   site[@name='site2']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Credit**: Thanks to [@Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) for this fine suggestion.

Comment: I would also mention that XSLT 2.0 allows it to be more compact by simply writing `<xsl:apply-templates select="site[@name='site3'], site[@name='site4'], site[@name='site1'], site[@name='site2']"/>`.

Comment: Yes, that's a great suggestion.  Answer updated.   Thanks!

Comment: I need to more specify what exactly I would like to do. I have site1 - site10 and then site11 - site100 and this exact 10 sites need to be after site100. But in real I dont know how many sites definition is only I know that I need to remove this 10sites.

Comment: If this answer does not help, yes, I agree that you'll have to better specify exactly what you would like to do.

Comment: Please let me know if my explanation is well or need to more specify my intention.

Comment: As I've said in my previous comment, if I've not answered your question, you will have to explain how not.

Comment: It looks like the OP needs first ten elements in input to be last on output, after all the other elements. It looks like implementation would need some index-range-based selection.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon: You're welcome to add a new answer with your interpretation of OP's intent, but extending an already strained comment chain on a four-year-old question whose OP hasn't been on SO for over a year is unlikely to be productive.

Comment: @kjhughes thanks for asking. I have in the meantime found a solution for my problem. You're right, I have adapted my solution to this question and added a proper answer below.

Answer (score 0):

### The OP question, more precise

Late in the game, [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450150/xslt-switching-order-of-elements/36451305?noredirect=1#comments-36451305) it looked like what OP needed was not filter by **name** to reorder two items out of four, but apparently to extract the first **ten** items and output them after all the **other** items (which exact number is not known when writing style sheet).

### Principle of solution

Apply the template just twice, using `position()` operator:

```xml
  <xsl:template match="sites">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[position()>10]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[10>=position()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

or (less readable, but does not confuse some incomplete parsers and syntax highlighters):

```xml
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[position()&gt;10]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[10&gt;=position()]"/>
```

### Reproducible solution

This file:

```xml
<configuration>
  <sites>
   <site name="site1"/>
   <site name="site2" />
   <site name="site3"/>
   <site name="site4"/>
   <site name="site5"/>
   <site name="site6"/>
   <site name="site7"/>
   <site name="site8"/>
   <site name="site9"/>
   <site name="site10"/>
   <site name="site11"/>
   <site name="site12"/>
   <site name="site13"/>
   <site name="site14"/>
   <site name="site15"/>
   <site name="site16"/>
   <site name="site17"/>
  </sites>
</configuration>
```

is transformed into this (lacking some line feeds):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <sites>
    <site name="site11"/>
    <site name="site12"/>
    <site name="site13"/>
    <site name="site14"/>
    <site name="site15"/>
    <site name="site16"/>
    <site name="site17"/>
    <site name="site1"/>
    <site name="site2"/>
    <site name="site3"/>
    <site name="site4"/>
    <site name="site5"/>
    <site name="site6"/>
    <site name="site7"/>
    <site name="site8"/>
    <site name="site9"/>
    <site name="site10"/>
  </sites>
</configuration>
```

by this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|*|processing-instruction()|comment()|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()|processing-instruction()|comment()|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="sites">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[position()&gt;10]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="site[10&gt;=position()]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tested with

```sh
xsltproc -o out.xml sheet.xsl in.xml && cat out.xml
```